# Tkinter - вертикальный Tab Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, виджет, tab

Есть ли в tkinter возможность сделать вертикальный tab widget? Я искал ответ на этот вопрос на зарубежных форумах, но всё безуспешно

Comment: Разве что "на коленке" сделать свой виджет из фреймов и лейблов.

Comment: в принципе можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вы ищете вертикальную панель вкладок для отображения страниц, то ... такая возможность в tkinter есть, но готового решения нет. Хотя просторы интернета огромны, может я и ошибаюсь. Посмотрите Qt 5, класс QTabWidget, там она есть.
Дополнение. Ошибался. Нашел интересное и простое решение с переносом верхних вкладок на боковую панель ttk.notebook с помощью ttk.Style.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909169/python-tkinter-side-notebook-tabs

Comment: спасибо за ответ